# Query total size before extracting frames from movie

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to extract all the frames as individual images from a 2 hour movie using ffmpeg the following way:

```
ffmpeg -ss 05:00 -i <input> -t 05:00 filename%05d.png
```

Is there a way to somehow get an estimation from ffmpeg or another program on the total size of the extracted images beforehand?

Comment: It's possible but not very practical. We can write the encoded PNG images to PIPE, and count the number of bytes that were written to the PIPE. Example (in Linux): `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f image2pipe -vcodec png pipe: | wc -c`. It is not practical because it's going to take a long time (about the time it takes to write the PNG images to files, unless the disk is very slow). We may also try encoding 1% of the frames and multiply the size by 100, but it's not accurate.

Comment: While [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) Most of the approaches would be only approximate. The only instance in which it would be exact would be if you are writing to an uncompressed PNG (or another uncompressed format), which would be disgustingly impractical due to filesize, this would be a matter of simple math (i.e. dividing the length of video converted by the framerate and then multiplying that by the filesize of an uncompressed image of a single frame).

Comment: However, you could also probably get a fairly accurate approximation *with* compressed images by just extracting one frame and substituting it for the above value.
Do keep in mind that a PNG is almost definitely not the most efficient solution for your situation. There is a decent possibility of an image format existing that would not require a reencoding, and there are certainly image formats that would encode much faster with a smaller filesize